# Elm: Fold specific values of multiple lists

Tags: elm

```
games =
    [ { id = 1
      , points =
            [ { player_id = 1, score = 20 }
            , { player_id = 2, score = 10 }
            , { player_id = 3, score = 0 }
            ]
      }
    , { id = 2
      , points =
            [ { player_id = 1, score = 20 }
            , { player_id = 2, score = 5 }
            , { player_id = 3, score = 0 }
            ]
      }
    , { id = 3
      , points =
            [ { player_id = 1, score = 20 }
            , { player_id = 2, score = 5 }
            , { player_id = 3, score = 10 }
            ]
      }
    ]
```

I have a list of 'games' records which each have a list of points for each player.
Is it possible to `fold` each score of each player across each game to display a 'total'.

Something like:

```
[ { player_id = 1, score = 60 }
, { player_id = 2, score = 20 }
, { player_id = 3, score = 10 }
]
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a double fold, where the key code is

```
main : Html msg
main =
    let
        go { points } acc =
            let
                goInner { player_id, score } accInner =
                    Dict.update player_id (updater score) accInner
            in
            List.foldl goInner acc points
    in
    List.foldl go Dict.empty games
        |> toString
        |> text

updater : Int -> Maybe Int -> Maybe Int 
updater  score existingVal =  
    existingVal
        |> Maybe.withDefault 0 
        |> (+) score
        |> Just
```

See [https://ellie-app.com/gq8VFfS8Ja1/0](this ellie)
This gets you the answer you want albeit in a slightly different format